# Is there a good way to determine if a variable is referencing a user defined function?

Tags: variables, types, coldfusion, user-defined-functions

The isValid function doesn't support this capability as far as I can tell, and there is no built-in "isUDF" or "isFunction" function. So far, the best I've been able to come up with is

```
findNoCase("func", myUDF.getClass.getSimpleName()) neq 0
```

When used on a UDF, the Java method `getClass().getSimpleName()` always seems to return a value with the substring `func` in it. I know very little about Java, though, so I have no idea how reliable this is.

Is there a better way to identify a reference to a function?

Comment: Why do you need to determine this? We may be able to provide a better answer if we know the actual use case

Comment: Curiosity, mainly, but it began with a real world situation. A while back, I started writing a UDF that translates a struct into an OOXML-based (MS-Office) document. This was in response to the bug-infested spreadsheet functions introduced in CF9, which were a major let-down for my colleagues and I. Since I didn't know much about OOXML, I decided it would be useful if the struct could include references to other UDFs that could handle any variations I hadn't thought of. That's all way beyond the scope of this question, but it is what got me wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`isCustomFunction()`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/IsCustomFunction) or [`isClosure()`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/IsClosure). CFML should not require two functions here, but due to - I suspect - poor understanding of the concept of closure on the part of the Adobe ColdFusion team, they kinda messed this up. Commentary on this: "[Am I right to think this is stupid?](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/am-i-right-to-think-this-is-stupid.html)"

Comment: Wow, how did I miss isCustomFunction? It's even in CF8! Fortunately, I don't have to worry about isClosure() yet since we're still on CF9.